# Javascript Array/JSON Library

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Basically I need some sort of library/set of functions that will allow me to perform advanced functions on arrays.

For example:

```
var jsondata = "SearchResponse":{ "Version":"2.0","Query":{ 
"SearchTerms":"sushi"},"Web":{ "Total":15000000,"Offset":0,"Results":[ 
{ "Title":"Sushi - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","Description":"In 
Japanese cuisine, sushi (寿司, 鮨, 鮓, sushi?) is vinegared rice, usually 
topped with other ingredients, including fish (cooked or uncooked) and 
vegetables.","Url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Sushi","DisplayUrl
":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Sushi","DateTime":"2008-06-
09T06:42:34Z"}]}} /* pageview_candidate */}

var filterdata = filter(jsondata, {"Title":"Sushi - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"});
```

And then `filterdata` will contain all results in jsondata that have the Title `Sushi - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, `jsondata` is an Object, not an Array; however the `jsondata.Web.Results` property is an Array.  With that in mind, you could make use of the [JavaScript Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
var results = jsondata.Web.Results.filter(function (value) { 
    // Return true if you want this 'value' object to appear in the 'results' Array.
    return (value.Title === "Sushi - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia");
});
```

If you want to do more serious work with Arrays then it would be sensible to include a Collections Framework; the most popular one for JavaScript is [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).  A solid understanding of Collections will pay off dividends in the future for your programming career.

Comment: Note that the native `filter` method is [not available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in IE < 9, that’s why underscore.js implements it where not natively available.

Comment: Gotta love browse compatibility ;)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/). You probably won’t be able to write code exactly as in your question, but it comes near to it:

```
_.filter(jsondata.Web.Results, function (val) {
    return val.Title === "Sushi - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [PHP.js](http://phpjs.org/). It brings PHP power to JavaScript.

Comment: I would definitely prefer the rather clean JavaScript API over PHP’s messed up library. Moreover, the native JavaScript `filter` is faster than any self-coded version.